# I need to set up GCM / FCM push notifications for an app. I don't know anything about server side implementation. What should I read / research?

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm a computer science major at a summer internship. I've taken most classes in my major except Operating Systems & Distributed Systems.

What do I need to understand in order to set up a lightweight demo of GCM / FCM for phone.

I've programmed in Android Studio before, but it was mostly interface design.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best place to start is probably with a complete working example. That you can find right here on [Firebase Cloud Messaging Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging). This starter guide should answer questions such as "what you need to understand to setup FCM".

Please follow [the above Firebase Cloud Messaging guide](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging) and try to get your FCM going. You can always post here when you encounter problems after you have failed to resolved them on your own.

Comment: Could I do a git pull of Firebase Cloud Messaging Quickstart , and run the app on my phone? I can quite tell from the README file. It would be great if I could

Comment: Yep. You can do a clone of the repository. Something like: `$git clone https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android.git` - alternatively you can simply download the `.zip` of the entire repository. By the way, if you find my answer helpful, please accept the answer so that your question can be marked as answered. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Visit [this](https://medium.com/glucosio-project/whats-new-in-firebase-cloud-messaging-and-how-to-migrate-from-gcm-578019c2167d#.6azmoxxj0) link for complete guide, where you can see GCM vs FCM and a complete demo.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, If you are starting right now and are relatively newer to the push notification/GCM/FCM realm ditch GCM, begin with FCM. Google now uses FCM to send push notifications to devices and highly recommends older users to upgrade to FCM. A simple internet search on how to setup FCM should suffice.

Best of Luck :)